# Configuring osCommerce

Tags: oscommerce

I got a project to improve a WWW-store which is based on OsCommerce. I have no experience on it so how can I configure it as payment modules gives a warning:

```
include(/var/www/vhosts/shop.fi/httpdocs/includes/languages/english/modules/payment/banktransfer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/shop.fi/httpdocs/admin/modules.php on line 128
```

And backups won't either work as it says

```
Error: Backup directory is not writeable.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two problems should really be very easy ones. For the first one, you probably just need to put the "banktransfer.php" language file in its directory, under /languages/english/modules/payment as you can see in your error notice. If you don't have a backup of this file, you can always upload the default file from a fresh OSC copy and change the labels in the file as you need, if so.

For the backup directory error, is really the same problem. I obviously don't know what backup directory you had, but you could just have a look in the admin or try to find it via FTP, is probably something like "backup", "backups" or the translation in Finnish? Then just change the permissions via FTP, probably to 777 (or Read + Write + Execute by Others).